# Snipping tool with highlight/write functionality?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I'm looking for something similar to Snipping Tool for Ubuntu that has the highlight functionality. Screenshot does not have this functionality and I'd like to avoid using an intermediate tool like Gimp to highlight/write on screenshot image.

Is there a tool for ubuntu/linux that can take a screenshot and has highlighting and/or other write functionality?

Comment: My Shutter's plugins do not include the highlight functionality.

Comment: You can always write a script ([example](https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/36456d94a87c3d6867e466a219f84844)) to first take a screenshot and then immediately start an image editor for post-processing if you'd like to keep the amount of manual steps at a minimum.

Comment: flameshot (described in the marked duplicate) or hotshots would be the applications most likely fulfilling your needs.